# Battlefield 4 ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG DirectX error

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-4

I don't think I've ever been so pissed at an error in a video game before, I've been struggling with this thing for the past few days.

[Here is the error message I get every time Battlefield 4 crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqTqL.png).

I have tried all the fixes listed [Here](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/DirectX-function-GetDeviceRemovedReason-failed-with-dxgi-error/m-p/2715082#M121195), as well as some more obscure fixes I found across the internet, to which none have worked. I previously thought that this error was appearing because I was overheating due to running 120 Hz, but that isn't the case, as today I got this error 4 times already playing at locked 60 FPS, and did some monitoring with GPU-Z, and I didn't go over 60-70 degrees Celsius (Max temp of the GPUs are 93 degrees Celsius).

PC Specs:

Laptop Model: Sager NP9377

- Display: 1920 x 1080 at 120 Hz
- Video Cards: Dual nVIDIA GeForce GTX 880M 8.0GB in SLi
- Memory: 16 GB (8x2) Dual Channel DDR3L/1600 RAM
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4810MQ (2.8~3.8GHz)
- HDD: 7200 RPM 1 TB Western Digital Travelstar

I run Ultra settings with no Motion Blur, 80 Degree FOV, no Post-Antialiasing (FXAA), 2xMSAA, no VSync, and 110% 1920x1080 Downscaled Supersampling. I average 75-90 FPS, but I do drop as low as 30-40 in intense tank fights where explosion effects are right in my face.

Running 344.75 (latest at time of post) Nvidia Driver

It's pretty rediculous that a AAA game that's a little over a year old is having a game-breaking problem with DirectX, does anyone here know of a solution?

Fixes I have already tried:

- Disabling Origin Ingame
- Unparking CPU cores
- Downloading an older driver, confirmed not working with two different drivers, one two versions old, another 10+ versions old
- Running 60 FPS capped to reduce GPU load
- Repairing the Battlefield 4 Install
- Deleting the .cab files from the Battlefield 4 DirectX folder and reinstalling
- Running Origin as administrator
- Reinstalling DirectX

Fixes I have found and not tried:

- Downclocking (I shouldn't have to downclock, call me stubborn, I refuse.)
- Reinstalling the Entire Game

Fixes I have tried that might be the source of the problem

- Played 2 matches of BF4 without SLi enabled
- Running borderless windowed mode (Jittered and was horrible, but I didn't crash while using it)
- Forcing 60 FPS makes the game stable for a considerably longer period. This implies there is some sort of conflict between DirectX, Battlefield 4, and managing GPU clocks (possibly the drivers). I see all over the place people solving this issue by downclocking 10%. Regardless, 60 FPS is fine, I can still usually get through 4-5 games before crashing which is good enough. If this is the case, then I can only hope that one of these groups finds the solution, or I'm gonna have to deal with this error for, well, ever.

**UPDATE:** I played 2 matches medium settings (-FXAA) on one card, averaged about 85 FPS, and I didn't crash. can't confirm if there is no crash yet though, since I have, in uncommon circumstances, gotten though 2 games in SLi. Regardless, I didn't buy a computer with SLi so I could play AAA titles on medium with 1 GPU. At least we likely know what the problem is now, does anyone here know why SLi might cause this DirectX error?

Comment: Umm.. Looks like it's saying that the device was removed... Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a display driver issue to me and from what you say you have not tested this properly yet?

Comment: Yeah I tried a really old driver. I haven't tried the Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare driver yet though, so there is a chance with that. The weird thing is that it doesn't seem to be a driver issue because I heard of no one else having an issue with this current driver, and I had this same problem a long time ago on another driver.

Comment: Well great, it doesn't seem to be a driver error. I went back two drivers (CoD Advanced Warfare driver), and I got the same error after about 45 minutes of playing. This is getting rediculous, am I the only person in the universe with this issue? I'm getting desperate for possible solutions, so I think a full game reinstall might help fix this, but somehow I'm doubting it, as I already addressed all DirectX relevant areas. Trying to debug the message isn't giving me great luck either, could it be that my video card is disconnecting?

Comment: Have you tried forcing the game to run in single card mode just to see what happens? Do you know if it is always the game graphics card getting the error? Have you played any other game of similar performance requirements to see if the same happens?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try playing in single card mode on the lower settings for a while, will report back later; and no, I have never gotten this error on any other game in my gaming history.

Comment: I played 2 matches medium settings (-FXAA) on one card, averaged about 85 FPS, and I didn't crash. can't confirm if there is no crash yet though, since I have, in uncommon circumstances, gotten though 2 games in SLi. Regardless, I didn't buy a computer with SLi so I could play AAA titles on medium with 1 GPU. At least we likely know what the problem is now, does anyone here know why SLi might cause this DirectX error?

Comment: The second card might be going bad.

Comment: I'm doubting that. I got this laptop just a few months ago, I have no problems in any other games, and I have read other people get nearly the same problem, and exact error message as said on the second post here: http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/Battlefield-4-keeps-crashing-on-PC-Jan-9/td-p/1724995/page/15 Also not to mention that borderless windowed mode works flawlessly, minus the horrible stuttering.